# Laravel after convert working query Argument 1 passed after convert

Tags: php, sql, laravel, oracle

I am converting working sql query with laravel builder. And I do not see nothing wrong in this query but laravel return this error ( to Illuminate\Database\Connection::prepareBindings() must be of the type array, string given, called in ). My final target is to add sub select. This is my query.

```
$testquery = DB::select(`id as TYP_ID`,`description as TYP_CDS_TEXT`)
    ->addSelect(TRIM(SUBSTRING_INDEX(constructioninterval, '-', 1)))
    ->addSelect(TRIM(SUBSTRING_INDEX(constructioninterval, '-', -1)))
    ->selectSub(`SELECT displayvalue FROM 'passanger_car_attributes' WHERE passangercarid = id AND attributetype = 'Capacity_Technical'`, `TYP_CCM`)
    ->selectSub(`SELECT displayvalue FROM 'passanger_car_attributes' WHERE passangercarid = id AND attributetype = 'NumberOfCylinders'`, `TYP_CYLINDERS`)
    ->selectSub(`SELECT displayvalue FROM 'passanger_car_attributes' WHERE passangercarid = id AND attributetype = 'EngineType'`, `TYP_ENGINE_DES_TEXT`)
    ->selectSub(`SELECT displayvalue FROM 'passanger_car_attributes' WHERE passangercarid = id AND attributetype = 'FuelType'`, `TYP_FUEL_DES_TEXT`)
    ->selectSub(`SELECT displayvalue FROM 'passanger_car_attributes' WHERE passangercarid = id AND attributetype = 'BodyType'`, `TYP_BODY_DES_TEXT`)
    ->selectSub(`SELECT displayvalue FROM 'passanger_car_attributes' WHERE passangercarid = id AND attributetype = 'AxleConfiguration'`, `TYP_AXLE_DES_TEXT`)
    ->selectSub(`SELECT displayvalue FROM 'passanger_car_attributes' WHERE passangercarid = id AND attributetype = 'Tonnage'`, `TYP_MAX_WEIGHT`)
    ->selectSub(`SELECT GROUP_CONCAT DISTINCT displayvalue SEPARATOR ', '  FROM 'passanger_car_attributes' WHERE passangercarid = id AND attributetype = 'EngineCode' GROUP BY passangercarid`, `ENG_CODE`)
    ->selectSub(`SELECT displayvalue FROM 'passanger_car_attributes' WHERE passangercarid = id AND attributetype = 'Power' AND displayvalue LIKE '%kW'`, `TYP_KW_FROM`)
    ->selectSub(`SELECT displayvalue FROM 'passanger_car_attributes' WHERE passangercarid = id AND attributetype = 'Power' AND displayvalue LIKE '%kW'`, `TYP_KW_UPTO`)
    ->selectSub(`SELECT displayvalue FROM 'passanger_car_attributes' WHERE passangercarid = id AND attributetype = 'Power' AND displayvalue LIKE '%PS'`, `TYP_HP_FROM`)
    ->selectSub(`SELECT displayvalue FROM 'passanger_car_attributes' WHERE passangercarid = id AND attributetype = 'Power' AND displayvalue LIKE '%PS'`, `TYP_HP_UPTO`)
    ->from(`passanger_cars`)
    ->where(`modelid`, `=`, `.$model_id.`)
    ->orderBy(`description`, `ASC`)
    ->orderByRaw(`TYP_PCON_START ASC`)
    ->orderByRaw(`TYP_CCM " ASC`)
    ->get();

 $data['test'] = $testquery;
```

Comment: Your ```php where(`modelid`, `=`, `.$model_id.`) ``` is weird. What is "$model_id" ?

Comment: $model_id is getting from function variable, this is correct id from url - Example:  public function model_modif($model_id) and route:
Route::get('/modif/{model_id}', 'TecDocController@model_modif');